# ItemSize loses its function after exporting Mathematica cells as HTML

Tags: grid-layouts, html

```
resultList=WordData/@{"aha","bib"};
len=Length@resultList;
Column[Table[Grid[Map[Item[Text@Style[#,FontSize->50,FontColor->RGBColor@@RandomReal[{0,1},3]],Background->RGBColor@@RandomReal[{0.5,1},3],FrameStyle->AbsoluteThickness[2]]&,resultList[[i]],{2}],Alignment->{{Center,Center,Center}},Frame->All,ItemSize->{30,5}(*,Spacings\[Rule]{{5,20,10},1}*)],{i,2}],Background->LightRed]
```

I found that the ItemSize setting will no longer work properly when converting the output cell to HTML format.

[image]
[image]

——————

Note: I want to convert the cell generated by Grid to HTML format with content is in text format not gif.

As cormullion showed in the answer, when the output content is gif pictures in HTML file, they look good.

Comment: The other version of your question [on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15714716/933113) is probably better. It's not clear here whether you want a reason, think it's a bug, or want a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not clear what you're looking for, but, with a slightly modified version of the code (from your web page):

```
list = DictionaryLookup[x__ /; x == StringReverse[x]];

SeedRandom[1];

col = Column@Riffle[
  Framed[#,
    Background -> RGBColor[RandomReal[{0,1}, 3]],
    FrameMargins->2] & /@ list,
  Framed[
    TableForm[#, TableSpacing->{2,5}], 
    Background -> RGBColor[RandomReal[{0,1}, 3]],
    FrameMargins->2] & /@ (WordData /@ list)];

Framed[col, Background->Lighter@Pink]
```

On the left is *Mathematica*, on the right is the HTML page. I think they did a pretty good job.

[image: two windows]

Comment: Hi, cormullion, I've modified the question and the question is concise now.